# Where do you get pics for your designs?

Tags: image

And also, do you use pics found online in your projects?

Comment: Should be tagged 'Subjective'

Comment: What is subjective about it? You either do or do not get pics from certain places.

Comment: This is a question for many programmers.. Some ask why, i say that some developers have difficulties creating nice good looking images and backgrounds for applications and websites.

Answer (score 7):

There's always:

[Stock.XCHNG, the leading FREE stock photo site!](http://www.sxc.hu/)

From the website:

> Browse through the categories of our
>   huge gallery containing over 350.000
>   quality stock photos by more than
>   30.000 photographers! Need a wallpaper for your desktop or illustration for
>   your blog? Need a pic for your
>   commercial website design? Looking for
>   inspiration? Have a look around.
>
> Share your photos with fellow
>   designers! SXC is a friendly community
>   of photography addicts who generously
>   offer their works to those who need
>   them free of charge. If you have some
>   nice photos that you'd like to share
>   with others, join us! Not only it
>   feels great to share, you will also
>   get a huge exposure for your work!

Answer (score 4):

I get mine from [iStockphoto.com](http://www.istockphoto.com/index.php).  You may search royaly-free images and photos from the site.

Answer (score 3):

For my personal website, I use some images from Flickr. The only difference is that I don't just grab the first few pictures that show up on the search results; I use [Advanced Search](http://www.flickr.com/search/advanced/) and modify my search to display just the images tagged with a Creative Commons license. That's one less headache for me with regard to copyrights ;)

Answer (score 2):

There's this nasty thing called copyrights... If you are taking images from the tubes you need to make sure that you are allowed to use them in the fashion that you want.

Answer (score 1):

Found pics depends if they may be used. When I'm looking for pictures I usually make use of Flickr

Answer (score 1):

I use IstockPhoto.com as the prices are cheaper than most 'Professional' royalty free sites, and the Quality is much better than most of the free sites.

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you learn how to make them yourself? There's no reason to stay dependent on other sources for something you could easily do yourself. You're the only one that knows exactly what you want.